# Why UnitCovert doesn't work with Fit?

Tags: fitting, data, dataset

I need to find the Hubble constant (Ho) in light years, from some data, the exercise tells me that the constant of the hubble is the slope of the line.

data:
 r1 is in MegaParsecs.

```
r1 = UnitConvert[Quantity[{1.52, 3.45, 2.37, 0.62, 1.16, 1.42, 0.67, 1.24, 0.79, 1.0,1.74, 1.49, 1.1, 1.27, 1.53, 1.79, 1.2, 2.35, 2.23, 2.06, 1.73},"Megaparsecs"], "LightYears"]
```

and v1 is in Km/s

```
v1 = Quantity[{650, 1800, 1300, 300, 800, 700, 400, 600, 290, 600,940, 810, 600, 730, 800, 800, 580, 1100, 1140, 900, 650},"Kilometers"/"Seconds"]
```

I used Transpose.

```
data1 = {r1, v1}\[Transpose];
```

and then Fit

```
aj1 = Fit[data1, {1, x}, x]
```

but I have this error message...

> Fit::fitm: Unable to solve for the fit parameters; the design matrix is nonrectangular, non-numerical, or could not be inverted.

I dont know why, and  I need to get the constant for my homework

Comment: Looks like `Fit` cannot deal with units. Try `Fit[QuantityMagnitude@data1, {1, x}, x]`. Then you can add the units to the slope and intercept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fit = Fit[QuantityMagnitude@data1, {1, x}, x]
(* 17.5294 + 0.000151023 x *)

Show[Plot[f, {x, 1*10^6, 1.2*10^7}], ListPlot[QuantityMagnitude@data1]]
```

Slope units: km/s/ly, intercept units: km/s

[image]