# How to perform a LinearModelFit on a data-set with units of measurement?

Tags: fitting

[image]

And i want to obtain the equation of the fit but with unit of measurement?

Comment: You could take the magnitude and fit then restore the units later. See this answer: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/199561/72682